# What is the error called when numbers are confused with letters?

Tags: confusables, typography, errors

In serial numbers etc., there are many cases where you can't tell if the intended character is a number or a letter. For example, the number `0` and the letter `O`, the number `1` and the letters `l` or `I`, and so on.

Is there a name for this concept/problem?

Background: I'm writing a spell corrector for my search engine that handles this situation. I'd like to know what this concept is called so I can document it properly.

Comment: I don't know of a name for this type of error. I'd suggest "look-alikes." I am wondering if this type of confusion is becoming less common. When I took a typing class a looooong time ago, the manual said that one could substitute l ("el") for a 1 ("one") and O ("Oh") for a 0 ("zero"). I'm guessing they're not doing that anymore.

Comment: Here's a guy who agrees with you: http://www.returncustomer.com/2006/10/30/zero-versus-the-letter-o/

Comment: @rajah9 Back when we had typewriters, most typewriters I used did not have a digit "1" key, so you had no choice but to use a small letter "l". I also used many typewriters that had no exclamation mark: We were instructed to type an apostrophe, back space, and type a period. I always thought this was odd: how tough would it have been to add a couple of more keys to eliminate these clumsy work-arounds? You already had 40 or so keys. What, would it have broken the budget to add two or three more?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A [homoglyph](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/homoglyph) is a *character identical or nearly identical in appearance to another, but which differs in the meaning it represents.*

Wikipedia has a detailed article on [homoglyphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) as well as one on [IDN homograph attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) where *phishers* take advantage of this property to mislead their victims.

As for your spell-corrector, you should be able to class such occurrences under something along the lines of *homoglyph errors* or *homoglyph conflicts*. However, it's a technical term which might possibly be a little too esoteric for your audience.

Answer (score 2):

The error is called a *homoglyph error*.

Characters likely to lead to homoglyph errors are referred to as *confusables* in Unicode parlance.

The distinction is because glyphs depend upon the font as well as the character, what could be a pair of homoglyphs in one font, may not be in another (e.g. `0` and `O` look quite distinct to me right now, but may not in another font, while `Τ` and `T` look identical to me right now, but may be clearly distinct in another font).

Hence *homoglyphs* for the confusable shapes, and *confusables* for the characters likely to be rendered with them.